# remove collection object from Generic List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, generic-collections

Sorry for posting this question again, as I thought I had resolved the issue!!!I need to collection of Users assigned to a particular Role, where Role is an entity which has Users as property. My aim is to remove the assigned users from that role and insert newly assigned users for that role I applied the following code, which I am not able to remove the users assigned to that Role :

```
Role DeleteUsers = new Role();
List<Role> role = new List<Role>();

//Deleting the users from the selected Role
DeleteUsers = RolesList.FindOne<Role>(r => r.RoleID == roleID, r => r.Users);

DeleteUsers.Users.Clear();
this.Save<Role>(DeleteUsers);
```

And how to insert the newly assigned users, where I have a roleID and list of userIDs as string array.

Comment: should `lstRoleUsers` be renamed to `role` and `role` deleted?

Comment: What type is `this`?  Is it some kind of context for an ORM?

Comment: lstusers contains the collections of users from Role Entity under that particular role, which is to be deleted and then insert newly assigned users

Comment: This code is defined in the DataAccess layer......

Comment: type "this" is meant for db...coz here the operation is performing directly to DB

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on the implementation on the `this.Save<T>()` method.  Are you using an ORM?  What type is `this`?

Also, your variable naming conventions are quite misleading.

Comment: type "this" is meant for db...coz here the operation is performing directly to DB

Comment: What I had done above is Clear the users from the object "DeleteUsers" and save the changes directly to DB ie this.Save<>.

Comment: I understand, but you need to paste the code inside your Save() function for us to understanding why your change isn't saving.